# Passing bigger data in a service-oriented architecture

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, distributed-system

I've got a service-oriented architecture with many systems talking to each other, but ultimately passing through a web front-end app. What would be a good way to pass a view stored on one app, that would be passed to the front-end app for rendering to the ultimate user?

The reason for doing this is the app in which the view resides is the logical place to control the information, and I just want the front-end to simply render the document. Sometimes this could even be a form that would take an input (and that makes it even more complex). I'd love to see how others may have handled this.

The question is, is doing it this way advisable, and what may be a solution for how to do it?

Comment: You shouldn't be sending a view, you should send a representation (JSON is a good format for that) and let the final app handle the view generation.

Comment: @MaurícioLinhares Agreed. Trick is, I've tried writing out the html as a big block of text that get's sent to be rendered, but this is clumsy on the sending app to edit. Need a way to gracefully create views that can be easily converted.